# how to check if a file exists and create one if it's missing, while the path to the file is incomplete as below

Tags: python, glob

I have to create a empty text file called `file.txt` under this path

`/home/project/test*/today/file.txt`

test* changes each time like test_product or test_1 etc..

I tried the following code:

````
    if(os.path.exists("/home/project/test*/today/file.txt"):
        print "Found"
    else:
        open("/home/project/test*/today/file.txt",a).close()```
````

I got this error

````
        ```IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/project/test*/today/file.txt'```
````

I understand I can use glob to search the files with paths like * , but I am unable to figure out how to create a file while having * in the path.

Comment: Your code is not syntactically correct. I don't even see how the interpreter would figure that out.

Comment: You need to figure out what the `*` is going to be, because the `open()` call isn't going to do that for you. If no file exists in any of the directories that match `test*`, in which one of them do you want to create the new file?

Comment: the * changes each time hence I left it as . *

Comment: Let me ask you a question @tim91, lets suppose you have folders in /home/project/test1,/home/project/test2... /home/project/testn. Would you code touch a file in each one? Your question is logically incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Your code logically doesn't make any sense. What you're basically saying is

```
if the file exists: display the text Found
otherwise the file does not exist, so try to open the file that does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you why it doesn't work. `os` module does not support wildcards.

If you wanted to use wildcards `*` you could use glob.

```py
import glob
import os
from pathlib import Path

def check_for_files(filepath):
    for filepath_object in glob.glob(filepath):
        if os.path.isfile(filepath_object):
            return True

    return False

file_to_check = "/home/project/test*/today/file.txt"

if not (check_for_files(file_to_check):
   Path(file_to_check).touch()
```

Comment: He has already said he is not using wildcards. He means it as the file name is arbitrary.

Comment: :( just a badly worded question.